# What instances do MS SQL triggers fail to execute?

Tags: sql

I'm creating a mechanism to monitor inserted and deleted data on a table. My question is, how reliable a trigger is? What instances do triggers fail?

The structure is simple, a table, two triggers, one for insert and one for delete. Both triggers will insert data ("deleted `<id>`", "inserted `<id>`") to another table.

Comment: One instance where people might *think* that triggers are failing is when they've written a trigger that only expects one row in `inserted`, which then silently ignores other rows when a multi-row statement executes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sir, can you give me link to and article that explains what you've said? I think it's worth studying. Thank you!

Comment: A quick look at [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/09/23/common-sql-server-mistakes-_1320_-multi-row-dml-triggers/) looks alright - I searched for *common SQL Server mistakes trigger*. You might also try searching here on SO for sql server trigger questions - it usually comes up somewhere in answering those questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger will always be executed, but if an unhandled exception occurs during trigger execution, the whole transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: And if I try to insert data to the table and fail, the trigger will be executed? Or only when it is successful?

Comment: That would depend on trigger option used, such as `AFTER` (which fires  after execution is successful) or `INSTEAD OF` (which is executed instead of triggering SQL statement).

Comment: You're such a big help. Thank you!